# Filter out null values in Java 8 stream filter expression so exception is not thrown

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Java 8 stream expression that has 3 filters and works fine.
I want to guard against null pointer exceptions within the filters for most of the values.
This is the expression:

```
if(!purchasedTripSegments.isEmpty()) {
    filteredList = purchasedTripSegments.stream()
        .filter(segment -> PurchasedVendorType.RAIL.equals(segment.getVendorType()))
        .filter(distinctByKeys(segment -> Arrays.asList(segment.getBillingMethod(), 
            segment.getOrigin().getNumberCode(), segment.getDestination().getNumberCode(), 
            segment.getStopOff().getStopOffLocation().getNumberCode()))) 
        .filter(segment -> segment.getBillingMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(BILLING_METHOD_LOCAL) ||
               (segment.getBillingMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(BILLING_METHOD_RULE) &&
                segment.getDestination().getNumberCode() != 
                  segment.getStopOff().getStopOffLocation().getNumberCode())) 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So the VendorType cannot be null.
So the first filter will be fine.
The 2nd and 3rd filters can have nulls.
The objects (Origin, Destination, StopOff, StopOffLocation) can be null.
And the values (BillingMethod, NumberCode) can be null.

Is there a way to ignore the filter if any of the values in the filter are nulls?

I tried adding `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`
I have a test case that has a null destination object and the NullPointerException is thrown.

**UPDATE**
I updated the billingMethod.  But I am not clear on how to use Optional to avoid the null checks.

```
Optional<List<PurchasedTripSegment>> filteredList =  Optional.ofNullable(new ArrayList<>());

if(!purchasedTripSegments.isEmpty()) {
    filteredList = purchasedTripSegments.stream()
     .filter(segment -> PurchasedVendorType.RAIL.equals(segment.getVendorType()))
     .filter(distinctByKeys(segment -> Arrays.asList(segment.getBillingMethod(), 
                            segment.getOrigin().getNumberCode(), 
                            segment.getDestination().getNumberCode(), 
                    segment.getStopOff().getStopOffLocation().getNumberCode()))) 
     .filter(segment -> BILLING_METHOD_LOCAL.equals(segment.getBillingMethod()) 
                  || (BILLING_METHOD_RULE.equals(segment.getBillingMethod()) &&
                               segment.getDestination().getNumberCode() != 
                      segment.getStopOff().getStopOffLocation().getNumberCode())) 
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'm not sure how to apply the changes you suggested to my filter. I tried adding as written but the map() was not recognized.
The middle filter would be the most difficult.
How to check the objects and values for each segment?

**UPDATE**
As per the comment below implementing a Utility method using Optional.

```
private Optional<Integer> getDestinationCode(PurchasedCostTripSegment purchasedCostTripSegment) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(purchasedCostTripSegment.getDestination()) // empty for 'null'
                .map(Destination::getNumberCode);
    }
```

I do a null check for the incoming parameter.
I get an error that the method `getNumberCode` is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes such as the `billingMethod`, whenever it is possibly `null` inside the `List`, it should still work for comparison to get distinct values.
On the other hand, comparing them with some other String constant can be solved in the manner the user [FilipRistic suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62585231/1746118).

But, when it is about objects which could be possibly null and you want to access the inner attributes further down safely, you can make use of `Optional` and chain the accessors. For a sample amongst those, while you want to access the `numberCode` of your destination which could possibly be null, you can have an accessor in `PurchasedTripSegment` class to expose this:

```
Optional<Integer> getDestinationCode() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.getDestination()) // empty for 'null'
                   .map(Node::getNumberCode);
}
```

With similar changes for other accessors, your overall code would update and change to something like:

```
filteredList = purchasedTripSegments.stream()
        .filter(segment -> PurchasedVendorType.RAIL.equals(segment.getVendorType()))
        .filter(distinctByKey(segment -> Arrays.asList(segment.getBillingMethod(),
                segment.getOriginCode(), segment.getDestinationCode(),
                segment.getStopOffLocationCode())))
        .filter(segment -> segment.getBillingMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(BILLING_METHOD_LOCAL) ||
                (segment.getBillingMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(BILLING_METHOD_RULE) &&
                        segment.getDestinationCode().equals(segment.getStopOffLocationCode())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!  Let me work on that.

Comment: But one question...why is the `getNumberCode` of type Node?

Comment: @GloriaSantin I just mimicked the class for `Destination` and named it `Node`, you can replace it with `Destination` if that's your class name. The type of `numberCode` is still Integer and that's just a map operation.

Comment: I don't have access to the PurchaseTripSegment class or Location class that is Destination.  So, I am created a method in the Utility Class that I need this functionality.  I pass the PurchaseTripSegment in as a parameter.  To add the Optional functionality into the Location class for the getNumberCode method to work, would i add another Optional.ofNullable to the getDestinationCode method?

Comment: @GloriaSantin If its a utility method that you are introducing then it might look something like `Optional<Integer> getDestinationCode(PurchaseTripSegments segment) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(segment.getDestination()) // empty for 'null'
                   .map(Node::getNumberCode);
}`. This of course, relies on the `segment` being `Nonnull`, other wise `Optional.ofNullable(segment).map().map()` could bean alternate.

Comment: I implemented the first approach. Checked the segment for null and added a method to the Utility class as above but I am getting a compile error that `getNumberCode` is not recognized.  That is the name of the get method.  So I am confused as to why it is throwing that error.
I posted my method above under **UPDATE**

Comment: In my Optional method above, I see how the Destination is optional but the value returned by `getNumberCode` needs to have some Optional indication also in case it is null.  Doesn't it?

Comment: Got it running. Filtering not occurring in the last filter when doing a compare (not equal)

Comment: @GloriaSantin are you filtering using `equals` over `Optional` elements?

Comment: yes. I have the filter compiling.  But I want to add a default value if the numberCode is null.  Trying to add `orElse` and setting a value but getting the error that it is expecting an Optional<Integer> and found Integer.  I will post my latest code...

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't any way for filter to know that since it doesn't know in which way you will use element inside `Predicate`, your only solution is to perform the check for null yourself.

Note that you can avoid check in cases where you are comparing to constant that you know isn't null, instead of writing:

```
segment.getBillingMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(BILLING_METHOD_LOCAL)
```

You could write it like this:

```
BILLING_METHOD_LOCAL.equalsIgnoreCase(segment.getBillingMethod())
```

This will avoid NPE but it only helps you in few cases not all of them, for other cases you will have to perform check or maybe refactor to return type `Optional` and your condition could look something like this:

```
segment.getDestination()
    .flatMap(d -> segment.getStopOff()
        .map(s -> s.getStopOffLocation)
        .filter(s -> s.getNumberCode() == d.getNumberCode()) )
    .isPresent();
```